# Perl regex replace numbers with themselves, just one higher

Tags: regex, perl, numbers

I have a text, how can I replace all numbers in it with themselves just one higher?

I've tried things like the following:

```
$buffer_content=~s/(\d)/($1++)/g;
```

Comment: What did you get as the response in that attempt? Just the literal string "2++"? Also would you need it to work with numbers of length greater than one digit?

Comment: This _may_ just qualify for the worst use of regex ever :-)

Comment: yes i just got 2++, it would need to work with numbers of greater length than one digit, but the current answer does that so its all good.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `s///e` - evaluation modifier and you can put arbitrary perl codes in second part.

```
$x = "hello 3";
$x =~ s/([0-9]+)/$1 + 1/eg;
print $x;

// hello 4
```

ref: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Search-and-replace

Comment: your code remind me about simple factorial computation `print "input factorial number\n> ";
$_ = <>;
$_ = join" ", (1..$_);
1while ( s/(\d+)\s(\d+)/$1*$2/e);
print;
`